# Is it possible to present a camera view in front of a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

iOS 10.3.1

I have a map that is part of a fairly deep view hierarchy, and the map has some buttons on it to present additional full screen 'details' views to the user wrapped in a navigation controller.

So the user is on the map and taps a button and that triggers the "displayFormForIdentifier:navigWindowTitle:" method below.

The 'details' view is pushed onto the navigation controller and displayed to the user.  This 'details' view has a camera button on it.
When the user taps the camera button, I'm trying to present the camera on top of the UINavigationController so the user can take a picture.

The problem is when the user taps the camera button, nothing is happening, and I'm assuming the navigation controller is obscuring the camera view.

I believe the reason I'm not seeing the camera view is because I'm trying to present the camera view on a view that doesn't seem to exist in my view hierarchy per this check ... `po [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject] recursiveDescription]`

So 2 questions...

(1.) My navigation controller and its subview(s) seem to be the entirety of my view hierarchy after I present the navigation controller.  I'm within my AppDelegate class.  My AppDelegate is has the code that's trying to present the camera view.  Can I obtain a reference to this navigation controller from within my AppDelegate?

(2.) Can I use this navigation controller to present a camera view?  Or do I need to do this another way?

```
-(void)displayFormForIdentifier:(NSInteger)identifier navigWindowTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    UIViewController *viewWithCameraButton = [MyViewControllers getViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
    viewWithCameraButton.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    viewWithCameraButton.navigationItem.title = title;
    viewWithCameraButton.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(formDone)];

    theNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    theNavigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    [theNavigationController pushViewController:viewWithCameraButton animated:YES];

    [mapViewController presentViewController:theNavigationController animated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

Another perspective on this problem is shown here below.

Note that I have two competing view hierarchies... one held by the rootViewController, and one held apparently by the UIWindow and navigation controller.

I'm trying to present the camera from my rootViewController, but that view hierarchy isn't active when the UINavigationController is active, and I don't know how to present a camera view in front of a UINavigationController.

```
(lldb) po [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject]
<UIWindow: 0x15592120; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x15592b80>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x155923b0>>

(lldb) po [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject] recursiveDescription]
<UIWindow: 0x15592120; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x15592b80>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x155923b0>>
   | <UITransitionView: 0x1840d0e0; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1732a4d0>>
   |    | <UILayoutContainerView: 0x1749a730; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x16ec4900>; layer = <CALayer: 0x18509620>>
   |    |    | <UINavigationTransitionView: 0x17498d40; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x16e731b0>>
   |    |    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x185a5820; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x16ae0f40>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x173f83c0; frame = (0 64; 768 960); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 500; layer = <CALayer: 0x171775c0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x16fda3b0; frame = (0 0; 768 35); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 502; layer = <CALayer: 0x1681afa0>>





(lldb) po [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
<TabBarController: 0x15642ed0>

(lldb) po [((UIViewController*)0x15642ed0).view recursiveDescription]
<UIView: 0x1564d8d0; frame = (0 20; 768 1004); autoresize = W+H; tag = 23456; layer = <CALayer: 0x1564d9b0>>
   | <IGSlideTabView: 0x15643420; frame = (0 0; 768 1004); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x15591940>>
   |    | <UIView: 0x15591c10; frame = (0 0; 768 969); autoresize = LM+W+RM+TM+H+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x15591e00>>
   |    |    | <UIView: 0x1564d740; frame = (0 0; 768 1004); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 2345; layer = <CALayer: 0x1564d820>>
   |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x16974f10; frame = (0 0; 768 1004); autoresize = W+RM+H+BM; tag = 1111; layer = <CALayer: 0x1696baa0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x1698cc10; frame = (0 0; 768 44); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 1010; layer = <CALayer: 0x1698f6d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIToolbar: 0x16b40320; frame = (0 0; 768 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+BM; tag = 2000; layer = <CALayer: 0x1687db00>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing the cameraVC use this

```
[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewWithCameraButton]
```